# Custom Tab bar item with system image

Tags: uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar item with a custom style, and I'd like to use a system image with it. The image dropdown in Interface Builder lets me select from a number of images, but only those from "Project" actually show up.

[image]

This has been asked before, and the answers are basically: System icons are for system styles. You cannot change the icon of a system item. Okay, but the `System Item` is set to `Custom`, and the `Image` field is there for a reason. How can these system images be used?